# Pandas Multindex: iterate rows and add specific values to create a new variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame with Multindex (*id* and *datetime*) and one column named X1.

```
                                X1
id          datetime          
a1ssjdldf   2019 Jul 10          2  
            2019 Jul 11         22  
            2019 Jul 12         21
r2dffs      2019 Jul 10         14  
            2019 Jul 11         13  
            2019 Jul 12         11
```

I want to create a new variable X2 where the corresponding value is the difference between the X1 value of the same row and the X1 value of the previous row. But every time it sees a new id the corresponding value has to be restarted from zero.

For example:

```
                                X1          X2
id          datetime          
a1ssjdldf   2019 Jul 10          2           0
            2019 Jul 11         22          20  
            2019 Jul 12         21          -1
r2dffs      2019 Jul 10         14           0
            2019 Jul 11         13          -1
            2019 Jul 12         11          -2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) by first level and replace missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['X2'] = df.groupby(level=0)['X1'].diff().fillna(0, downcast='int')
print (df)
                       X1  X2
id        datetime           
a1ssjdldf 2019 Jul 10   2   0
          2019 Jul 11  22  20
          2019 Jul 12  21  -1
r2dffs    2019 Jul 10  14   0
          2019 Jul 11  13  -1
          2019 Jul 12  11  -2
```